# Userform Getting Reinitialized when it's being Loaded through the command VBA.Userform.Add("UF")

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, userform

I am stuck in an issue of VBA coding. There are two userforms named as "UsersForm" and "Registration".

In "UsersForm" there is a commandbutton named as CreateProfile, by clicking on it it should show "Registration" form.

For that purpose a procedure named as "ShowNextUF" has been written in a Module in which I am supplying the arguments as show below:

```
Private Sub CreateProfile_Click()  ' <----its an activex Command button of the userform "UsersForm"

 Call ShowNextUF("Registration", Me, True)

End Sub
```

In Module:

```
Sub ShowNextUF(ByVal NxtUF As String, ByVal PrevUF As Object, Optional ByVal UnLd As Boolean = False)

 Dim nUF As Object

 Set nUF = VBA.UserForms.Add(NxtUF)
 If UnLd Then Unload PrevUF
 nUF.Show

End Sub
```

Now the issue is: when I want to check the value of a textbox of the userform "Registration", then it's works fine..

```
Private Sub tbStdName_Change()     '<---- A TextBox of "Registration" userform

 StudenName = UCase(tbStdName.Value)

End Sub
```

But it does not (below); actually in this case the "Registration" form is getting Initialize again. Don't know why it's getting Reinitialized.

```
Private Sub tbStdName_Change()     

 StudenName = UCase(Registration.tbStdName.Value)  '<---- Reinitilizing...

End Sub
```

I need to use this one: UCase(Registration.tbStdName.Value) in another new userform when I call that new userform after hiding the "Registration" form. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Add will Add a new userform to the collection of userforms. Perhaps you are looking for Show?

Comment: @ArnovanBoven, Thanks for your kind reply...I am passing the string argument as 'NxtUF' in the procedure 'ShowNextUF' for loading and as well as activating the next userform... I have around 32 Userforms in my project, that's why I'm calling the procedure to minimize the code size... Please guide me how to activate a new userform by using the name(<--String) of that userform without using '.Add' function...

Comment: @ArnovanBoven Yes, I am ultimately looking for show! but I need to set an object to VBA userform which can be showed by '.show' command...Will passing the argument : 'NxtUF' as Userform help? I mean If write something like: 

Private Sub CreateProfile_Click()  

 Call ShowNextUF(Registration, Me, True)

End Sub


and in Module :


Sub ShowNextUF(ByVal NxtUF As Object, ByVal PrevUF As Object, Optional ByVal UnLd As Boolean = False)

 If UnLd Then Unload PrevUF
 NxtUF.Show

End Sub

Comment: @TinMan 
Is not '.Add' is adding a new instance? Otherwise,why that instance expires when it's default name is called (e.g : Userform.TextBox.Value) within it's own  Module!

Comment: Not quite sure I follow your reasoning, but the idea is that you Add a UserForm once, then Show/Hide it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

@Arno van Boven

Thanks for your kind information which gave me the idea that '.Add' will add new collection in USerform...Just tried the idea and it got resolved!

The way to get rid of this is to pass the argument as Object instead of String...

```
Private Sub CreateProfile_Click() 
   Call ShowNextUF(Registration, Me, True) 
End Sub
```

and in Module :

```
Sub ShowNextUF(ByVal NxtUF As Object, ByVal PrevUF As Object, Optional ByVal UnLd As Boolean = False) 
   If UnLd Then Unload PrevUF 
   NxtUF.Show 
End Sub
```

Thanks Again...
 Cheers!!!!